# Airflow Dagrun Prioritization

Tags: airflow, priority-queue

**Is there a means to prioritize a Dagrun based on input parameters?**

Situation:
I have a Airflow Dag whose pipeline holds sequential long-running tasks. Based on input parameter value, I need to prioritize some of the instances of Dagrun.

Example:
Dag name: `DagX`
concurrency of Dag: `16`.
During dag run, I am passing input parameters value for property named`level`, which can be from `1 to 5`.

Requirement:
DagX is triggered multiple times with different `level` value. As Dag concurrency of 16, most dagruns get added to queue.
I need dag-runs with higher `level` value, should be picked earlier/sooner from the queue, i.e., *I need to prioritize Dagrun based on input parameters.*

What I have evaluated/came across:
I see that we have `priority_weight` at task level, but I need some similar stuff at `dag run` level.

Comment: If a Dagrun have tasks with higher `priority_weight`, will such dagrun get a higher priority of getting picked from queue?

Comment: There are certain reviews to close this question.
Just to clarify, question has only one primary query: **How to prioritize a Dagrun at runtime based on input parameters**

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this for runs of the same DAG. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @RNHTTR: We have assigned different priority levels to customers. Dag pipeline is same irrespective of customer. There are always 1000s of such long-running Dags in queue. We need option to allow some of these customers to jump the queue.

Comment: @RNHTTR: there are many reasons why you could want to do this. Let's say you have a DAG you need to recreate or backfill, and maybe that takes a few days or weeks of compute. Your customers will expect to continue to receive daily data drops from the latest data, but you will want to slowly (re)generate the old data. As is, it will run the oldest dates first, which means days/weeks of delays in getting your customers their daily data if you're unable to prioritize this ahead of backfill.

Comment: sounds like you can just use the [backfill CLI command](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#backfill)? Also, it's a bit hacky, but could you use a separate DAG specifically for backfilling? Then you should be able to manually trigger it (or via REST API) to have a start/end date.